# How to truncate html without breaking the tags?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

How to ensure that all html-tags were closed? The problem arises because I want create some sort of excerpt for every article. For example someone writes an article like this:

```
Hi everyone, I'm just an article and I have few <strong>tags</strong> inside <em>of me</me>
```

If I cut this message just after "tags", I get an unclosed tag .
How can I check with Django all user's input text before saving it to DB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Django 1.7, there is a specific template filter called [`truncatechars_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html):

> Similar to truncatechars, except that it is aware of HTML tags. Any
>   tags that are opened in the string and not closed before the
>   truncation point are closed immediately after the truncation.

Also see [`truncatewords_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords-html).

For Django<1.7, you can either use `truncatewords_html`, or make a custom filter based on the one implemented in 1.7 ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/484f3edf1e79388f73dcb07e39d79d0c5029ae9e/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L276-L290)), or use this [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1477/) (have not tested it). Also see relevant to the snippet blog post: [Safe truncation of HTML](http://ole-laursen.blogspot.com/2009/05/safe-truncation-of-html.html).

Answer (score 4):

For Django 1.6 there is truncatewords_html available no need to create a custom filter.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords-html