# Problem by adding truncateworld and safe tags

Tags: django

I use Django 1.11 for my blog.
I illustrate all acticles in my first page by a title, an image and a few words.

For the few words, I'm using this method :

```
 {{post.text|safe|linebreaks|truncatewords:"50"}}
```

I use a text editor and sometimes, I use for example italic text :

```
<i/>Italic text</i>
```

Let's imagine the value of truncatewords is on "1". It means it returns :

```
<i/>Italic
```

There is my problem. Some HTML tags are still opened. It means that the italic text never end and It will be applied for the rest of the code.

Do you know if a trick or workaround exists ?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `truncatewords_html`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to truncate html without breaking the tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112970/how-to-truncate-html-without-breaking-the-tags)

Comment: I didn't know about this. Sorry for duplicate and thank you.